# How to set wi-fi in lock mode in API 29?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi

i'm using Google guide to mediaPlayer. To lock wi-fi from being disabled it's recommended to lock it while playing media via wi-fi:

```
val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val wifiLock: WifiManager.WifiLock =
    wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock")
```

But since API 29 `WIFI_MODE_FULL` is deprecated. So how can i lock wi-fi on API 29 and above?

P.S. should we also lock mobile internet connection or it's always available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some changes in Api 29 regarding **Wi-Fi performance modes**. According to the [Android 10 highlights documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights#wi-fi_performance_modes):

> Apps can now request adaptive Wi-Fi by enabling high performance and low latency modes. These can be a great benefit where low latency is important to the user experience, such as real-time gaming, active voice calls, and similar use-cases. The platform works with the device firmware to meet the requirement with the lowest power consumption. To use the new performance modes, call WifiManager.WifiLock.createWifiLock() with WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY or WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF. In these modes, the platform works with the device firmware to meet the requirement with lowest power consumption.

To support Api 29 you can now use [`WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY) or [`WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF) constants:

```
val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val wifiLock: WifiManager.WifiLock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY 
    else WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, 
    "mylock"
)
```

Comment: thank you. Can I use it for earlier API versions?

Comment: For earlier API versions you can use `WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL` or `WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF`

Comment: So we can use `WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF` for both then? Is there any difference betwen low latency and high performance?

Comment: `WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY` lock will be effective when app is running in foreground and screen is on, while the `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF` lock will take effect otherwise.

Comment: Heads up to anyone finding this now: `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF` is also deprecated as of API 34, the only option now is `WIFI_MODE_FULL_LOW_LATENCY` and nothing else.